# Designing a Login and Registration form using a table view

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to the iPhone development.I want to design a login form for an app
which uses a table view .also the user verification from a server.Kindly guide me .A detailed and simplistic explanation would be gr8ly appleciated.....thanx..:)

Comment: or else we can create fields in view directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using iOS5.0, then you can use storyboard to create static tableview as follows:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_an_Xcode_Storyboard_to_Create_a_Static_Table_View

Answer (score 0):

You need to have custom UITableViewCell.

Check this tutorial: [Custom UITableViewCell](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/)

You can also download the example source code from there for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

There are already beautiful fully developed components to do that. Check for example: http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog. There you can find a complete tutorial.